# Colorbar repeating range labels in Matlab

Tags: matlab, plot, visualization, colorbar

I'm plotting some data in Matlab and when I add a colorbar into my plot the range labels are drawn repeatedly to the plot. Here is a minimal working example:

```
events = 1000000;
 x1 = sqrt(0.05)*randn(events,1)-0.5; x2 = sqrt(0.05)*randn(events,1)+0.5;
 y1 = sqrt(0.05)*randn(events,1)+0.5; y2 = sqrt(0.05)*randn(events,1)-0.5;
 x= [x1;x2]; y = [y1;y2];

%For linearly spaced edges:
 xedges = linspace(-1,1,64); yedges = linspace(-1,1,64);
 histmat = hist2(x, y, xedges, yedges);
 figure; pcolor(xedges,yedges,histmat'); colorbar ; axis square tight ;
```

You can get the `hist2`-function from here:

http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/9896-2d-histogram-calculation/content/hist2.m

This is what I get from running the code:

[image]

If I remove the colorbar command from the code above I get:

[image]

Any ideas why is this problem occurring? I have met this problem before also...
My operating system is 64-bit Windows 7 Enterprise and I have Matlab R2012b (8.0.0.783)

Thank you for any help :)

Comment: see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18021851/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As user @nkjt stated the answer to this problem can be found here:

http://www.mathworks.nl/matlabcentral/answers/53874

for me the following piece of code worked:

```
set(gcf, 'renderer', 'zbuffer');
```

And it resulted as:

[image]